# How to fetch unchecked checkbox value into a cursor in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Here is my PL/SQL code to fetch checked checkbox value in a button's dynamic action.

```
DECLARE
IHC_ID_Y VARCHAR2(9);
IHC_ID_N VARCHAR2(9);
CURSOR Y IS
    SELECT regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level)
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
CURSOR N IS
    SELECT regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level)
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level) IS NULL;
BEGIN
    OPEN Y;
    OPEN N;
    LOOP
        FETCH Y INTO IHC_ID_Y;
        EXIT WHEN Y%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO INFANT_RESPONSE (INF_ID, IHC_ID, IR_DESCRIPTION) VALUES (:INF_ID, IHC_ID_Y, 'Y'); 
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE Y;
        LOOP
        FETCH N INTO IHC_ID_N;
        EXIT WHEN N%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO INFANT_RESPONSE (INF_ID, IHC_ID, IR_DESCRIPTION) VALUES (:INF_ID, IHC_ID_N, 'N'); 
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE N;
END;
```

However, I met a problem in this part,

```
CURSOR N IS
    SELECT regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level)
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level) IS NULL;

 LOOP
        FETCH N INTO IHC_ID_N;
        EXIT WHEN N%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO INFANT_RESPONSE (INF_ID, IHC_ID, IR_DESCRIPTION) VALUES (:INF_ID, IHC_ID_N, 'N')
```

As you can see, when I change the condition from `IS NOT NULL` to `IS NULL`, the values being fetched will all be nulls and hence cannot be inserted into the table rows. Is there any way to fetch the unchecked checkbox values?

Comment: Please share the example value of the parameter: `INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS` containing nulls and not nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a different approach:

- insert checked health conditions (as you know how to identify them; it is your cursor `Y`); I used it as well, but within the cursor FOR loop as it is way simpler to use - you don't have to explicitly open it, pay attention about exiting the loop nor when to close the cursor - Oracle does that for you.
- in order to insert unchecked health conditions, do that for all conditions that exist in a table you use to create those checkboxes that aren't inserted as "checked" in the first step

Something like this:

```
begin
  -- Checked conditions (using your cursor, but as a cursor FOR loop)
  for cur_y in 
    (SELECT regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level) ihc_id_y
     FROM DUAL
     CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
    )
  loop
    insert into infant_response (inf_id, ihc_id, ir_description)
    values (:inf_id, cur_y.ihc_id_y, 'Y');
  end loop;

  -- To insert unchecked conditions, insert values that exist in the table
  -- that contains ALL health conditions (let's call it LIST_OF_HEALTH_CONDITIONS)
  -- that aren't inserted as "checked" in the above cursor FOR loop
  insert into infant_response (inf_id, ihc_id, ir_description)
  select :inf_id, 
         h.ihc_id,
         'N'
  from list_of_health_conditions h
  where h.ihc_id not in (select r.ihc_id
                         from infant_response r
                         where r.inf_id = :inf_id
                           and r.ir_description = 'Y'
                        );
end;
```

Can't test it as I don't have your tables nor data, but - unless I made a typo, that should be OK.

Comment: I figured out the solution just now, using a similar approach. First, I select all the values from my orginial table with all the health conditions and use ```MINUS``` operator to remove all the values from cursor Y so the remaining values will be unchecked values stored in cursor N.

Comment: That's OK. However, loop will be slower than direct insert as you're inserting row-by-row, while option I suggested performs bulk insert. For small data sets you won't notice any difference, but - try to remember this discussion if you ever have to work with lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use `MINUS` set operator to achieve the result I want.

```
CURSOR N IS
    SELECT IHC_ID FROM INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS
    MINUS
    SELECT regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level)
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:INFANT_HEALTH_CONDITIONS, '[^:]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```